# How to split text in a data file with an even sequence? Python 3x

Tags: python, list, file, nested

I'm having trouble splitting text in a data file such that suppose the the data file consisted of:

```
Row 1
apple
bob
cat
dog
ear
fun

Row 2
glow
horse
idea
joke
kick
lemon

Row 3
money
new
odd
park
queen
run
```

I want to split it so that it becomes a nested list like the following:

```
[[apple, bob], [cat, dog], [ear, fun]], 
[[glow, horse], [idea, joke], [kick, lemon]], 
[[money, new], [odd, park], [queen, run]]
```

This is my work so far:

```
def text_file(data_file):
    nested_list = []
    main_list = []
    my_list = ''
    for index in data_file:
        index = index.strip()

        if (index in my_list):
            main_list.append(nested_list)
            nested_list = []

        else:
            nested_list.append(index)

    if (nested_list):
        main_list.append(nested_list)

    return (main_list)
```

but this returns:

```
text_file(open("data_file.txt", "r"))
[['Row 1', 'apple', 'bob', 'cat', 'dog', 'ear', 'fun'], 
['Row 2', 'glow', 'horse', 'idea', 'joke', 'kick', 'lemon'], 
['Row 3', 'money', 'new', 'odd', 'park', 'queen', 'run']]
```

Without **importing** anything, how can I achieve this? If possible what can I add into my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is split the file by `\n\n` (two newlines) which will give you the groups, then split the result of that by line, then use `zip` to step over the file appropriately to build your required lists, an eg:

```
s = """Row 1
apple
bob
cat
dog
ear
fun

Row 2
glow
horse
idea
joke
kick
lemon

Row 3
money
new
odd
park
queen
run"""

lines = s.split('\n\n')
for line in lines:
    words = line.splitlines()
    print([ [i, j] for i, j in zip(words[1::2], words[2::2]) ])

[['apple', 'bob'], ['cat', 'dog'], ['ear', 'fun']]
[['glow', 'horse'], ['idea', 'joke'], ['kick', 'lemon']]
[['money', 'new'], ['odd', 'park'], ['queen', 'run']]
```

Comment: @thestruggler You'd use `s = open('file.txt').read()` - not copy the data into your interpreter... also, where is editing of the data occuring?

Comment: @JonClements just ran your code on my system, it is also returning `Row2` and `Row3` in the output.

Comment: @JonClements got the same now, must be some indentation issue when I ran it for the first time. +1.

Answer (score 1):

something like this, using `regex` and `iterators`.

using `regex` split at `Row number`, and then you can either use `zip` or `iterator` to get the expected output.

```
In [8]: with open("data.txt") as f:
    spl=re.split(r"Row \d+",f.read())[1:]
    for x in spl:
        sp=x.split()
        it=iter(sp)
        print ([[next(it),next(it)] for _ in range(len(sp)//2)])
   ...:         
[['apple', 'bob'], ['cat', 'dog'], ['ear', 'fun']]
[['glow', 'horse'], ['idea', 'joke'], ['kick', 'lemon']]
[['money', 'new'], ['odd', 'park'], ['queen', 'run']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (nested_list):
    new_list = nested_list[1:]
    main_list.append(zip(new_list[::2], new_list[1::2]))
```

Try this out

The above code, instead of appending the nested list in the main list, first forms pairs of consecutive elements and then appends it.

Comment: You probably want to explain what this does and why it will solve the problem.